# Rails: collection_select with a collection of multiple nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, associations

I'm clueless in this:
I have a form where you can select which IP Address a port of a service is listening to.

```
<%= form.collection_select(:listener_id, Ipaddress.all, :id, :ipv4address, {include_blank: t("ports.select")}, { class: "form-control" }) %>
```

Given the following model:

- Customer has many Systems

  - System has many Networkinterfaces

    - Networkinterface has many IP Addresses
  - System has many Services

    - Service has many Ports

I want to connect "Ports" with "IP Address". As you can see, in my collection_select I create a collection of all IP Addresses. Even ones from another Systems or other Customers. That's not how I want this.

In another case I could do something like: `Customer.find(System.find(@networkinterface.system.id).customer_id).systems.all`, but I can't find a way how I could do my Collection now. I want to make a list of all possible IP Addresses on that system, or from all system of a customer.

Could someone lighten me up? What would be the easiest and what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do here is setup [indirect associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) that let you traverse the tree:

```
class Customer
  has_many :systems
  has_many :networkinterfaces, though: :systems
  has_many :ipaddresses, through: :networkinterfaces
end

class Networkinterface
  belongs_to :system
  has_one :customer, through: :system
end
```

Given a customer `@customer` you can just use the indirect association to get a list of ip addresses.

```
<%= form.collection_select(:listener_id, @customer.ipaddresses, :id, :ipv4address, {include_blank: t("ports.select")}, { class: "form-control" }) %>
```

Comment: You should also really rename your classes and associations according to the [Ruby Style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#naming-conventions). NetworkInterface -> network_interface. IPAdress -> ip_address. Your code is a PITA to read.

Comment: Thank you for this. It worked. And somehow it was a little bit obvious. Also thanks for your advice about my naming convention. To be honest, I was a bit concerned that pluralization and stuff wouldn't work with underscores in names like this. That's why I thought I keep it more safe like this. Probably it will be much work to rework everything. But I will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: You can just create a migration to rename the tables and then just use a search and replace to change the names. It's not that much work really. You will have to setup an inflection for IPAddress but that's really easy.